# Python variable scope - Global vs Local Scope clash

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

Based on the different conditions used in a if conditional check, the variable's global & local scopes are affected.

I tried running the below code in multiple online IDEs as well, **Almost all throws the error message in most runs & not all runs**

Can someone clarify the reason for the behaviour?

#Code Sample 1:

Within the function definition, Outside of if condition the variable holds no value !!!, And *throws error but not in all runs*

```
import random

a = 10

def f():
    if(random.randint(0,1) == 1):
    #if(True):
        a = 5
        print(f'Under if a is: {a}')
    print(f'Outside if a is: {a}')
    
print(f'Before & Outside f() a is: {a}')
f()
print(f'After & Outside f() a is: {a}')
```

And the output is:

```
Before & Outside f() a is: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    f()
  File "main.py", line 10, in f
    print(f'Outside if a is: {a}')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

#Code Sample 2:

Within the function definition, Outside of if condition the variable holds the local value instead of the globally assigned value

```
import random

a = 10

def f():
    #if(random.randint(0,1) == 1):
    if(True):
        a = 5
        print(f'Under if a is: {a}')
    print(f'Outside if a is: {a}')
    

print(f'Before & Outside f() a is: {a}')
f()
print(f'After & Outside f() a is: {a}')
```

And the output is:

```
Before & Outside f() a is: 10
Under if a is: 5
Outside if a is: 5
After & Outside f() a is: 10
```

Comment: You do realize that `a` inside the function is local variable, right? It is not the `a` from global scope, because you do assignment in the body of the function. Depending on whether the condition is True `a` may be defined or not when you try to print it.

Comment: The simple rule is: if you assign to `a` anywhere in a function (your `a = 5`), Python considers it local in this function. It will never, in this case, try to use a global variable with the same name if it happens not to be defined at some point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function) That said, note that using `global` is considered bad practice and better make your function take arguments and return values.

Comment: @buran. Understood, Unless the same named variable is assigned/modified in a function it is global, Else its local.

Comment: Also, my previous understanding was, local scope is the minimal code chunk limit, But it is actually the the entire function itself seems - Right?

Comment: Not entirely true, e.g. there may be nested functions. There is so called _LEGB rule - **L**ocal, **E**nclosing, **G**lobal, **B**uilt-n"_ Check https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding and https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4046632

Answer (score 0):

you declare a=10 outside the function scope, and then here:

```
print(f'Outside if a is: {a}')
```

you use `a` within the function, but only when the randomly generated number is 0.

For the code to work, you need to add this to the function

```
def f():
    global a
    if(random.randint(0,1) == 1):
    # and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Valentino :), It helps to clarify one portion of my query